# FPGA loads same bit file but the performance is different at different switch on times

Tags: configuration, fpga

Hardware design has 3 PCB's (each with 1 FPGA) connected through mother board. Communication between FPGAs is through GPIOs. Individually each FPGA code is taken care that there are no timing errors or warnings. But when we switch on and off 100 times, 90% times the output is correct and 10% times output is not okay. Once switch on if the output is correct, there is no change in the output for any amount of time. But when the output is not okay, we need to switch off and on the system. Can anyone suggest what extra efforts to be taken in the individual FPGA code for getting 100% performance okay.

All three FPGAs independently boots from its flash for power on and off. There is no inter dependency for booting.

Comment: Check for metastability issues. Properly synchronize the asynchronous inputs, make sure data crosses clock domains (if any) properly. It is possible your fsm is latching up in some state (possibly invalid) because of metastable inputs seen as different values in different parts of your design.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would check is the protocol on your GPIO. Assuming there is a clock from one fpga to other, and assuming that each fpga has its own internal clock, and assuming the gpio does not run anywhere close to max fpga frequency:

(1) make sure the clock edges for source fpga and the destination fpga are opposite (ie. if source clocks out data on rising edge, have the destination sample on falling edge).

(2) synchronize the destination gpio clock by the fpga own clock, by putting it through at least two flip flops go avoid anything metastable.